# Linked list in php giving errors

Tags: php, linked-list

Im new to PHP and I'm trying to make a linked list but it keeps on giving errors

```
<?php
class Node {
  private $value;
  private $nxt;
  function __construct($x) {
    $this->value = $x;
    $this->set_nxt(null);
  }
  function set_value($x) {
    $this->value = $x;
  }
  function get_value() {
    return $this->value;
  }
  function set_next($x) {
    $this->nxt = $x;
  }
  function get_next() {
    return $this->nxt;
  }
}
class linked_list {
  private $start = new Node(null);//error is here
  function __construct() {
    $start = new Node(null);
  }
  function add_name($nme) {
    $start = new Node($nme);
    if ($start->get_value() == null) {
      $start = new Node(nme);
      $start->set_next(null);
    } else {
      $temp = new Node($nme);
      $temp->set_next($start);
      $start = $temp;
    }
  }
  function show_all() {
    $temp = $start;
    while ($temp != null) {
      echo $temp->get_value();
      echo "<br/>";
      $temp = $temp->get_next();
    }
  }
}
?>
```

It would be great if you could tell me what I am doing wrong and how I should do it right. Please I just want to know what I am doing wrong with the PHP code. There is no need to tell me about linked list I just want to know what I am doing wrong with the implementation.

Here is the data I am working with :

```
$list = new linked_list();
$list->add_name("first");
$list->add_name("second");
$list->add_name("third");
$list->add_name("fourth");
$list->show_all();
```

and here is the error :

[image: here]

Basically its saying the $start in linked list class is a constant. i have commented on the place the error is coming from

Comment: *but it keeps on giving errors* can you explain what errors you are getting as well as some sample data to test it.

Comment: I have edited the post for better understanding

Comment: can you change `private $start = new Node(null);` to `private $start;` and try again?

Comment: and make all the `Node` methods public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least four errors to solve:

1. *`$this->set_nxt(null);`* in the constructor of the `Node` class: `set_nxt` is an undefined function (maybe you meant `set_next`);
2. *`private $start = new Node(null);`* in the `linked_list` class: you can't declare a property and initialise it with a new instance of a class (you can do it inside the constructor);
3. *`$start = new Node(nme);`* in the `add_name` function of the `linked_list` class: `nme` is an undefined constant (maybe you meant `$name`);
4. *`$temp = $start;`* in the `show_all` function of the the `linked_list` class: `$start` is an undefined variable (maybe you meant `$this->start`).

Comment: It seems that i have to create new instance of node class every time in any function i want to use. It is trouble some since i cant use the old values i store in it. is there any other way that i just create one instance and use it everywhere in other class?